# Where can I get complete information about Yugal Maha mantra?

Tags: scripture, mantras

I need complete information including correct spelling of Yugal maha mantra with reference. Also, does the mantra starts with Radhe or Radha?

Comment: Are you asking whether it is Radhe or Radha in the mantra?

Comment: Yes and also I am asking for complete information regarding this mantra example-mantra's origin, history of this mantra, name and verse no of a scripture where this mantra is found etc. In short complete information with valid proof.

Comment: [She chants this mantra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xq9AOcaZkVc) always before giving discourse on SB. It's "Radhe Krishna".

Comment: @Secret Nice bhajan

Comment: For Krishna mantra, consult Gautamiya Tantra. For Radha mantra, consult Narada Pancharatra.